# How to solve this sql topic?

Tags: sql, subquery

Let a and b be integer-valued attributes that may be NULL in some tuples. For each of the following conditions that may appear in a WHERE clause, describe exactly the set of (a,b) tuples that satisfy the condition, including the case where a and/or b is null.

```
(a) a=10 OR b=20
(b) a=10 AND b=20
(c) a<10 OR a>=10
(d) a=b
```

Kind of confused as to how to approach this problem. What exactly is this asking? It was in my textbook but we are learning about views and ER diagrams. Not sure how this ties into those topics.

Comment: (c) might as well just be `a is not null`

Comment: @MarcB - nope. Nothing fits c). Crap. You're right. I rwad it as and not or. My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) there will be two types of tuples:

- a = 10 and b can be anything including null
- b = 20 and a can be anything including null

From that you should be able to work out b) and c).

d) is interesting. There is only one type of tuple:

- a = b and a is not null and b is not null

Null never equals anything, not even itself.

Comment: How did you arrive at your answer for a?

Comment: The question is 'what does a tuple look like if it satisfies a = 10 or b = 20'. The obvious answer is that either a = 10 (and b can be anything) or b = 20 (and a can be anything). I can't make it much simpler that that. Can you think of a tuple which matches the question but which doesn't fit one of my two possibilities?

Comment: So, for b, it is only valid when a and b are 10 and 20. Thats the only way it will be true. Correct?   C is valid for pretty much anything except null.

Comment: Well, can you think of a tuple that matches (a = 10 and b = 20) where that might be false?

Comment: No, if the only variables we are looking at are a and b. I guess there could be other conditions that make the tuple false if a = 10 and b = 20. I am looking at the question like  




"The question is 'what does a tuple look like if it satisfies a = 10 AND b = 20'. "     Also, c is satisfied by "a is not null" as it seems to satisfy all the other conditions.